# Почему WebView на базе Ionic 3 медленно стартует?

Tags: webview, mobile-development, ionic

Собрал WebView с помощью данного модуля, по руководству внутри, но старт приложение очень медленный, долго отображается белый экран. Сайт не самый быстрый, тем не менее в браузере рендериться не так долго. Можно ли ускорить? И может WebView лучше делать другими средствами?

Доп. вопрос: Google Play и AppStore принимают вообще такие приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Старт приложения тормозит вес страницы. Если сделать простой Hello world - то и загрузка будет быстрее. Максимально облегчите страницу - сожмите скрипты, реализуйте динамическую подгрузку скриптов (но при дин. подгрузке будет тормозить интерфейс)

Comment: а кэширование asset`ов возможно в среде ionic?